# Suggestion for making Seasoned Advice easier to find

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been aware of **Seasoned-Advice** SE for some time because I occasionally see it mentioned in **Hot Network Questions**, however I am not a regular user.

Recently I wanted to find your site and couldn't. Why? Because I was searching for "cook" and "cookery" and had forgotten the name Seasoned Advice. There is no reference to "cook" in its description as shown below.

[image]

May I suggest an edit such as for example:

> **Seasoned Advice**
>
> Cookery advice for professional and amateur chefs

This will make you so much easier to find.

Comment: For what it's worth, "cookery" is not really a word in US English; an easier edit is probably just "chefs and cooks".

Comment: Is that +11040 for real?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you used your browser to search for 'cook'? Because if you use the dedicated search box, you'll definitely find it :)

[image]

(this works because the URL starts with 'cooking')

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I used Ctrl F on the list shown in my diagram. This does not find "cook".  I was simply suggesting  making the site  more findable in general (including via online searches). Presumably this would attract new members. From the lack of response, it seems that no-one cares!  That's okay by me - I already know where it is now.

Comment: Ctrl + F, that's exactly what I meant by browser search. The page doesn't load the entire list of sites. The [list of Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) does, but on that page, searching for `cook` doesn't help. So your request definitely has merit.